# SDFS filesystem automount on start-up

Tags: linux, filesystems, fstab

Just started to test http://opendedup.org/

So I did this:

```
# mkfs.sdfs /dev/vdb --volume-name=pool1 --volume-capacity=100GB
# mkdir /mnt/pool1
# mount.sdfs pool1 /mnt/pool1/
```

The result of this line is empty:

```
# ls /dev | grep pool1
```

How to automount on boot (fstab) instead of `mount devicename /mount/path` everytime?

And another question: how to place sdfs data on another location?
I have noticed that the

```
# mkfs.sdfs /dev/vdb --volume-name=pool1 --volume-capacity=100GB
```

didn't get any result - all data was stored somewhere in `\`. How to place them for example on `/mnt/vdb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local storages all sdfs data is stored in `/opt/sdfs/volumes/volumename` when mkfs.sdfs creates a volume with a path for deduplication. It takes about 300-400Mb for empty volume. Volume configs are stored in `/etc/sfds/`. So you can edit them later (size, etc...)

To redirect data to another path:

1. Mount partition to redirect sdfs data:

`# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3`

I don't want to benchmark is ext4 on top better or not in this case, I just used ext4 for example.

```
# mkdir -p /opt/sdfs/volumes/volume1
# mount /dev/sda3 /opt/sdfs/volumes/volume1
# mkdir /mnt/disk1
```

`/mnt/disk1` will be the `/path/for/deduplication`.

2. Create and mount sdfs volume:

`# mkfs.sdfs /mnt/disk1 --volume-name=volume1 --volume-capacity=856GB && mount.sdfs volume1 /mnt/disk1/`

3. Then (yes, as Esa Jokinen wrote above) for sdfs automount place in `/etc/rc.local` `mount.sdfs` command before `exit 0`.

Answer (score 1):

SDFS doesn't seem like a filesystem supported by the Linux kernel. The OpenDedup project is written in Java while the Linux kernel is written in C... there might be little gap..

Therefore, SDFS is not mounted with `mount` and could not be automatically mounted with `fstab`, but has it's own `mount.sdfs` command. You could for example add `mount.sdfs MOUNTOPTIONS &> /var/log/sdfs.log &` to `/etc/rc.local`.

What's with the `ls /dev | grep pool1`? If you mount to `/mnt`, there should be nothing new in `/dev`.

Comment: I thought that sdfs volums available as devices, that's why `ls /dev`. May be you also know how to place sdfs data on specified location of the disks? I have added a question on my first message.

Comment: There's `/dev/vdb` in your command. The `/mnt/vdb` should be fine. Just create a empty directory there first, i.e. `mkdir /mnt/vdb`.

Comment: Not the same, but thanks for the idea. `mkfs.sdfs /location/for/deduplication --volume-name=pool1 --volume-capacity=` when all data stored in `/opt/sdfs/volumes/volumname`.